# How many audio codecs are supported in Android RTSP streaming protocol?

Tags: android, audio, streaming, rtsp, rtsp-client

How many audio codecs are supported in Android RTSP streaming protocol. I am working on Android audio RTSP streaming, it's easy to implement the android RTSP streaming client.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(RTSP_URL);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

But the audio speech/media codec supported list is not specified in neither the Android API overview/reference nor the RFC spec.

Could anyone help to share some background of it?

- [media-formats from Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)
- [MediaPlayer from Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)
- [RTSP Package Summary from Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

The codecs supported may be different per device. For example some devices may decide only to support patent/royalty free codecs (don't know of any, but as an example...).

You can find the list of codecs a particular devices supports programatically with the getCodecs() method of AudioCodec:

```
public static AudioCodec[] getCodecs ()
```

One of the purposes of the SDP (session description protocol) is to allow either end of a connection negotiate which codecs to use from the set that they both support.

The Android documentation explains how codecs are 'exposed' to app developers:

> The Stagefright service parses the system/etc/media_codecs.xml and system/etc/media_profiles.xml to expose the supported codecs and profiles on the device to app developers via the android.media.MediaCodecList and android.media.CamcorderProfile classes.

What this is describing is the method that someone (e.g. a device vendor) who is adding a codec to a device uses to make that codec available to someone developing apps (e.g. regular app developers) on the device.

Once codecs have been aded in this way they will be returned when the above getCodecs() method is called.

Comment: But does the codec support follow the Android media codec support list defined in CDD? or a specific codec supported list defined in other specs?

Comment: If you mean does it use the same type 'numbers' then, yes I think it would have to and the documentation says: "type The payload type of the encoding defined in RTP/AVP.'. Remember this does not mean that every device will support every codec. It might help to look at the info at this link which explains how new codecs are added to the framework (at a vey low level) - see the section 'Exposing Codecs to the Framework': https://source.android.com/devices/media.html

Comment: I read [media_profiles.xml](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/media_profiles.xml?repo=device--moto--wingray) from official Google code and found <!ELEMENT Audio EMPTY>
  <!ATTLIST Audio codec (amrnb|amrwb|aac) #REQUIRED>, does it mean that only amrnb, amrwb and aac could be used in rtsp streaming? Thanks.

Comment: @Michael.Zhou - see above for a bit more explanation added to answer. You are reading that XML abovecorrectly but for the same device (a moto Wingray in the example in your link) there is also a media_codecs.xml file which contains a wider range of audio codecs. It would probably be worth you writing a simple test piece of code to query the codecs using the getCodecs() method and then write them to the logs for the device you want to use - this should give you the full list (I'm not sure if it would work on the emulator so I would test on a real device).